# Implicit arguments in WCF calls

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a number of WCF services on different machines that call each other.

Is it possible to attach some kind of trace_id to a WCF call so that it gets passed from client to server (and server could pass it implicitly or not to sub-servers that it calls) so that this ID can be logged everywhere for debugging?

Of course I could add traceId to the signature of every single method, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way of achieving the same thing.

Comment: It's already there. Just use [WCF tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730342.aspx), especially [End to End Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738749.aspx).

Comment: May be you'll also find helpfull operationcontext.sessionid (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.sessionid(v=vs.110).aspx)